# TextDecoration not applying in LazyColumn item

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've started a todo-list app to get into jetpack compose. Here's what I've got so far.

I have a composable for a Todo:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Todo(
    todo: TodoItem = TodoItem()
) {
    Row() {
        Checkbox

        Spacer

        if (todo.editing)
            EditTodo(todo, onEditingFinished = onEditingFinished)
        else
            TodoText(todo = todo)
    }
}
```

*I've omitted the styling bits in here to highlight the actual components*

For reference, here's the `TodoItem`:

```kotlin
data class TodoItem(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val done: Boolean,
    val editing: Boolean,
    val createdAt: Date,
)
```

The `TodoText` method is where I think my problem lies:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun TodoText(todo: TodoItem) {
    Text(
        text = todo.title,
        style = if (todo.done)
            TextStyle(
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough,
                color = Color.LightGray,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
            )
        else
            TextStyle(
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.None,
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
            )
    )
}
```

If the todo is done, I want to change the text style accordingly and as you can see from the following gif, the colour changes properly, but the decoration remains as `LineThrough`:

[image: Todo list checking item]

---

That said, I don't know exactly what's happening. I do put this all inside a `LazyColumFor` which I might not be recycling the views properly, there's also a viewmodel with mutable state here in the mix... All in all, there might be way more things at work here. I've added the code to github. If you want to check it, please use this [branch](https://github.com/fgoncalves/ComposedTodoList/tree/todo-list-update-issue). I plan to keep updating `master` with code changes.

Comment: I think what you should be doing here is to store the state of the selected item, you can do that with mutableStateOf and store the boolean value of done, then your code should react to that state when you click the item, this will recompose the composables when they are depending on that state. The problem I see is that it composes first time, but when you click it , it only reacts to the first composable that handles the click, the second one have been composed 1 time and need to recompose on any state change

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If I understand correctly I did this but to the entire list. Yes, I'll admit that it might not be the most performant solution. Every change to the list changes the entire state. If this part of the state update wouldn't be working, how come the todo gets unchecked and the colour of the text changes?

Comment: You can check this part of the state codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6

Comment: I get the state concept, but I'm struggling to understand how this is the issue here. If the state would be the problem, how come parts of the view get properly updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was an issue with the version of compose I was using, which was `1.0.0-alpha04`.

On `1.0.0-alpha06` the issue doesn't occur anymore.